# Typo3 8.7 Bootstrap_package 10.0.2 change footer background color

Tags: typo3-8.7.x

how can I change the background color of my footer without changing the css?
we run a multidomain site - for that reason we do not want to change the extension css. we found some constants and found, that changing $gray-900 is one possible solution. but $gray-900 is used in other context too - and it does not look like good solution ..

my setup is:
Typo3 8.7 Bootstrap_package 10.0.2

Answer (score 1):

I've found this way to override footer colors.
In output it's clean built css code without duplicates of classes.

First of all, you should create **custom-theme.scss** file and put it in your extension or fileadmin folder.
In this file you should define variables you want to override, then import **theme.scss** of bootstrap_package, using relative path:

**(custom-theme.scss)** /typo3conf/ext/**YOUR_EXT**/Resources/Public/Theme/custom-theme.scss

```
// variables you want to override
$footer-sections: ();
$footer-sections: map-merge((
  content: (
    background:                tomato,
    color:                     #fff,
    link-color:                $primary
  ),
  meta: (
    background:                tomato,
    color:                     #fff,
    link-color:                $primary
  )
), $footer-sections);

// relative path to theme.scss
@import '../../../../bootstrap_package/Resources/Public/Scss/Theme/theme';
```

After this when you have custom theme file, you should include it in Setup.
Go to **Template Tools (root page) -> Info/Modify -> Setup** (or into your setup.typoscript file) and paste code below:

```
page {
  includeCSS {
    # default is: theme = EXT:bootstrap_package/Resources/Public/Scss/Theme/theme.scss
    # in result here should be only one theme definition
    theme = EXT:YOUR_EXT/Resources/Public/Theme/custom-theme.scss
  }
}
```

This code will override bootstrap_package theme definition and use yours.

Result will be like expected:
[Footer background overriding result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ReTD.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could set the footer colors for each section via TypoScript Constant like so:

```
plugin.bootstrap_package.settings.scss {
    # Update footer colors
    footer-sections = (content:(background: $body-bg, color: $body-color, link-color: $primary), meta:(background: #f6f6f6, color: #313131, link-color: $primary))
}
```

For more Information, pls take a look at:
https://github.com/benjaminkott/bootstrap_package/wiki/Customize-Footer-Colors